# spring thymeleaf remove quotes in validation message

Tags: spring, validation, thymeleaf, properties-file

I am using Spring Thymeleaf and I have form validation messages in an external messages.properties file.

When I reference the message like this:

```
th:attr="data-error=#{field.error.required.field}"
```

as in the following input field declaration:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
       th:attr="data-error=#{field.error.required.field}" required="true"
       data-delay="100" placeholder="First name"/>
```

When the validation message appears in the browser, it has quotation marks as below:

```
"This is a required field"
```

How do I display the message without the quotation marks?

Here is some more code detail. The model object looks like:

```
public class UserSession {

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    private String email;
    ...
}
```

The form input looks like:

```
<div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')} ? has-error">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="email"
               th:field="*{email}" th:attr="data-error=#{field.error.invalid.email}"
               required="true" data-delay="100" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors" th:errors="*{email}"></div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

When I remove the `data-error` attribute and bind the message to the model object property directly, I get the default errors and not my message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to bind @NotBlank/@NotNull with your form class
>
> you can bind directly message = "error.message" // your properties variable

```
public class UserForm implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank(message = "error.message")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "error.message")
    private String lastName;

    // your other filed with Getters and Setters

    ...........................     
}
```

Your HTML code :

```
<form role="form" th:action="@{/signup}" method="post" th:object="${userForm}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <th:block th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${userForm.*}')}">
                <div th:utext="Common error message">Alert</div>
            </th:block>

            <div class="form-group input-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}? 'has-error'">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="firstName" />
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">Incorrect title</span>  
            </div>

            // your other filed with submit button          
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note :

- Common message append in header if form validation is fail
- form filed error message append as per your set message in form class

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I remove the 'data-error' attribute it defaults to the default error messages. I will update the question with more detail.

Comment: Yes because you need add **message** inside notEmpty annotation with *@NotEmpty(message = "key")* try this. otherwise its showing default message